# How to save the current state of switches in Android Studio?

Tags: android-activity, switch-statement, toggle, state

I know very little about programming. I downloaded Android Studio and started tinkering with it. I tried to make the app that they put on the tutorial and it worked. However I tried to add more functionality to it and I've failed so far. Excuse me if you see unnecessary junk on my code, I'm just kinda trying everything at first and I do feel a little misguided.

Anyways, onto the question. I have a Switch (id:toggle_text) with an OnClick action (change_font). When the switch is toggled it should change the font size of a different activity through intent1. Currently not only does it not send the font size variable (the variable keeps the default value you put on getIntExtra), but now that I tried to add the ability to save the current state it just shows errors. Here's the code:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import static com.example.myfirstapp.R.id.toggle_text;
import static com.example.myfirstapp.R.string.change_font;


public class ShowAnOption extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_an_option);
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("com.example.xyz", MODE_PRIVATE);
    toggle.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true));
}

public void change_font(View v) {

    int fssize;

    if (toggle.isChecked())
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.example.xyz", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true);
        editor.commit();
        fssize=20;
    }
    else
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.example.xyz", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", false);
        editor.commit();
        fssize=40;
    }

    Intent intent1 = new Intent (getBaseContext(), DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    intent1.putExtra("Font_Size", fssize);

}

}
```

It says "cannot resolve symbol toggle" on toggle.setChecked() and the if statement. What can I do to fix this? Also, why does it not get sent to the other activity? Here's the code on the other activity:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Intent intent1 = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    int Font_Size = intent1.getIntExtra("Font_Size",50);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(Font_Size);
    textView.setText(message);

    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_display_message);
    layout.addView(textView);
}
}
```

Thanks and sorry for the long read. If there's anything else that needs to be known let me know and I'll gladly show.

Answer (score 0):

We did not try to change the font size but here is how to use the switch widget.
Our design is two activities MainActivity and SwitchActivity we changed a CheckBox from unchecked to checked The switch is on the MainActivity code below

```
    setOnCheckedChangeListener();
private void setOnCheckedChangeListener() {
    swAll.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Switch On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intentSP = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SwitchActivity.class );
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("FONT","true" );
                intentSP.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity( intentSP );
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Switch Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now in the SwitchAcvity we capture the value from the intent and fire the method 
doWhat()

```
        Intent intentSP = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intentSP.getExtras();
    tORf = bundle.getString("FONT");
    doWhat(null);
```

And here is the doWhat method

```
    public void doWhat(View view){
    if(tORf.equals("true")){
        chkBoxOne.setChecked(true);
    }else {
Toast.makeText( SwitchActivity.this, "NOT TRUE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }
}
```